# Why does shutil.copy2 sometimes modify the files' st_mtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, shutil

I'm currently writing a little Python3 script for monitoring parts of my macOS filesystem. It checks selected folders for new and modified files and copies them (via `shutil.copy2`) into a review folder which I check from time to time. The test for modification uses a comparison between the `st_mtime` of the original and the (already) copied files. While testing it I encountered some strange behaviour: Some files got copied over and over again, despite being unmodified.

After some poking around I found out that `shutil.copy2` apparently doesn't always carry over the exact `st_mtime`. (I also tried out `shutil.copystat` explicitly, with the same result -- which isn't much of a surprise.)

To illustrate my problem: When I run the following code ...

```
from shutil import copy2
from os import stat

source = '/Users/me/myfile'
target = source + '-copy'
copy2(source, target)
print(stat(source).st_mtime, stat(target).st_mtime)
```

... the result sometimes looks like (not always):

```
1600616170.8300607 1600616170.83006
```

When I'm using the nanosecond version `st_mtime_ns` the result looks like:

```
1600616170830060720 1600616170830060000
```

Now my question: Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_mtime) say *"Time of most recent content modification"* about os.stat_result.st_mtime. So what is content? Does it include metadata? OS might be playing a role here...

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes, OS definitely plays a role! I've tried it under Linux (and Windows 10, if I recall correctly) and got perfect nanosecond matches. When I used the Finder under macOS I also got a perfect match. But when using `cp -p` in a terminal the mismatch occured. After that I installed [coreutils](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils) and tried `gcp -p`: Again perfect match. So this is kind of all over the place. I spent hours going through the CPython source code trying to figure out how it is implemented but wasn't successful -- my C is too rusty.